# Can I rephrase this sentence like this?

Tags: ambiguity

1. Plants die if there's no oxygen because plants need oxygen.
2. **Because plants need oxygen, plants die, if there's no oxygen.**
3. **If there's no oxygen, plants die, because plants need oxygen.**

Can I rephrase sentence 1 into 2 and 3 with the same meaning?

Comment: This sentence is what I made.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What do the parentheses represent? What modification is being made? It's not even clear what the logic of the sentence itself is.

Comment: Parentheses mean which modifies the main clause first. "Sometimes" or "conjunctional clause"

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify what semantic difference you think that makes and what question you have about it?

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Yes, of course, I made it in a different way!

Comment: The second 'plants' should be replaced with 'they' in all three sentences.